# Getting datetime data into the correct format arcpy python arcmap

Tags: python, datetime, strptime, arcpy, arcmap

I am using `datetime` in `Arcpy` to convert a `"Sample Date"` field in a feature class to the day of the year.  The date in the field is in a `month/day/year` format and it doesn't include any leading zeros (ex. `7/8/2018` instead of `07/08/2018`).

Whenever I try running the following line of code,

```
dtm = datetime.datetime.strptime(row, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```

I get the following error:

`ValueError: time data '[datetime.datetime(2003, 6, 3, 0, 0)]' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'`

The sample date field that I am using does not include any time data which I believe is where the two zeros at the end of the error message are coming from.  I just assumed that they were hours and minutes but I am not sure.

Does anyone know what the zeros are so that I can change my code to fit the correct format or how I can avoid the zeros altogether?  I tried `datetime.date` instead of `datetime.datetime` as well and still had complications.  I can post the long version of the code if needed but the code that I provided is the cause of the error message. I have included the link of the `datetime` reference I used. The website is for `strftime` not `strptime` but I believe that it works the same. Trying `strftime` throws an error as well. Link: http://strftime.org/

Comment: Can you please break this down into paragraphs or more code-based? I've just opened this on my phone and it's literally a wall of text

Comment: You should apply `strptime` to a string, not a `datetime` object. Your `datetime` objects do not have any format.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong datetime method. The error that you got shows that value in `row` is already a [datetime object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime).

`strptime` takes a string and a datetime string format and returns a datetime object.

For example this code: `datetime.datetime.strptime('2018/08/30 10:30', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')` returns the object `datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 30, 10, 30)`

`strftime` returns a string representing the date in the format specified.

You already have a datetime in `row` so you need to use `strftime` to convert that to a string.

The proper code to convert `row` into a date string would be:

```
dtm = row.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```

This will return the string representing the datetime. For example for the datetime object of `datetime.datetime(2003, 6, 3, 0, 0)` the returned string would be '2003/06/03 00:00'

Comment: Whenever I try that I get an error message that reads "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strftime' ".

Comment: If row is a list then you need to pass in the index of the list that contains the datetime object. So if the list only contains one thing, i.e. `[datetime.datetime(2003, 6, 3, 0, 0)]` then you would use `row[0]`. So then your code would be `dtm = row[0].strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')`

Comment: Thank you that worked.  The last line of the code is: 
   arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "DOY", dtm.timetuple().tm_yday)  which is supposed to take the dtm and calculate the day of the year from it and add it to a field called "DOY".  However, when I try this I get an error message that reads "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'timetuple' " so does that mean I need to do a strptime function on a new line after the strftime one to get the object back into a datetime format?  And if so what would that look like?

Comment: Just do the `.timetuple().tm_yday` function on the original datetime object: `row[0].timetuple().tm_yday`

Comment: I don't think you are using CalculateField correctly though. CalculateField can calculate a value for all records in the table at once so there is no reason to use it while iterating through the table row-by-row